# How to open a link in a new chrome tab, and include current tab's history in the new tab

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

On old versions of Chrome, when I open a new tab by pressing middle-mouse button, it keeps all the backtrack history from the old tab. But on a newer version, history is cleared when I open a new tab from the current tab. How can I revert it? Or is there a simple solution such as enabling a flag from chrome://flags ?

Image for illustration:

[image: tabs]

Comment: You could duplicate the tabs first, then left-click instead of middle-click. More tedious but it would work.

Comment: This seems like personal preference. A new tab logically shouldn't have a different tab's history, unless it's a duplicate. But you're right in that Chrome's default settings are terrible (e.g. downloading without prompting for desired directory; no option to prompt before closing all tabs, etc...)

Comment: bumping to see if anyone has any update about this...