# How to open a link in a new Firefox tab, copying the current tab history?

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-extensions, greasemonkey

This seems to be similar to [How to open a link in a new chrome tab, and include current tab's history in the new tab](https://superuser.com/q/1338940/990780) except I am asking about firefox in 2023:

I have a recollection that in the distant past, when one middle-clicked to open a link in a new tab, the old tab's history was carried over to the new tab. I don't remember when it stopped working for me but it was quite a long time ago.

Is there a simple way to get the old behaviour in current firefox?

---

I am using the current snap version of firefox on Ubuntu 22.04.

I don't know if the previous behaviour was the default or due to some addon I was using pre- Quantum/WebExtensions.

It may or may not be relevant that I currently use the [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) addon, so I mention it in case it is. However I don't see anything in its preferences that seems applicable.

Additionally, I have [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) installed. I haven't used it for anything very complicated and only have basic javascript knowledge, so I don't know if suitable hooks are exposed that would allow implementing this behaviour if more direct approaches don't exist.

Comment: re greasemonkey, perhaps there is some way to override middle-click to (a) [duplicate the tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/duplicate); (b) open the clicked link in the new tab; (c) jump to the new tab?

Comment: perhaps it was Tab Mix Plus that provided the history functionality? It seems to have a [openLinkWithHistory](https://github.com/onemen/TabMixPlus/blob/ae0730db2bbd66a69dce3ab90d5da15faedf507c/addon/chrome/content/minit/tablib.js#L1099) function